# how does vscode file explorer copy/paste work?

Tags: vscode-extensions

in vscode file explorer you can right click a file and choose the copy option. Then right click on a folder to paste the file into that folder.  How does that process work?  It does not appear to copy the file to the clipboard.

I want to click the path of a file in an .html file and have an extension do the equivalent of the file explorer copy option. Then click on paste to copy the file to the destination folder.

How would an extension copy a file or folder to vscode file explorer?

Comment: look how Node.js will do this with the `file` module